Trouble using the right module version installed in pipenv environment
I'm trying to run some Python code in VS Code in an environment.

Step one. Open cmd from the folder containing the environment, activate the environment, and run VS code


then:


Seems like VS Code has opened in the environment

But when I run some code, it complains that "Numba needs NumPy 1.21 or less" while pip freeze shows that that is indeed the case in that environment:


So, what am I doing wrong here?

This seems to be an issue with Numba incompatibility with NumPy.
Try to upgrade Numba (atleast to version 0.53).
pip install numba --upgrade

